# C# Dealing with dictionaries where values MAY (or may not) be arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, object, dictionary, collections

I'm working on creating a library which decodes JSON objects into c# objects that our users can then access, modify and resend. Some objects are predetermined, others are going to end up being non-predetermined (Though they do have a several standard possible formats). So the best way we found of managing these values with this is to create an object with a dictionary in it.

```
Dictionary<string, Field> _fields = new Dictionary<string,Field>;
```

Then all our objects can be fields, we create properties for established objects and an indexer/method to get any field including the non-predetermined ones.

```
public OurObject : Field

public T GetFieldByName<T>(string fieldName) where T : class
        {
            return _fields.ContainsKey(fieldName) ? _fields[fieldName] as T: null;
        }

public Field this[string index]
    {
        get { return _fields.GetFieldByName<Field>(index); }
        set { _fields.SetFieldByName(index, value); }
    }
```

Ok cool. But then I realized that some of these objects are actually arrays. Damn. ok, so back to the drawing board. But we're having a bit of trouble finding a good way to handle the generic access/management of these Array/Not Arrays.

The ideas we've come up with so far include:

- Creating a collection object extending from field and placing it in (FieldCollection), extending any field objects that are arrays from that.
- Changing Field in the dictionary to Field[] and perhaps adding a property to field "IsArray" (perhaps in conjunction with the previous point)

Are there any better ways of keeping a hash that keeps single objects or arrays of objects the same way? This will be a library so we want it to be as simple to use as possible for the user.

Comment: Any reason for not using existing JSON deserializers?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, check out [JSON.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/json). It will handle serializing/deserializing primitive types and dictionaries etc for you. It will also handle custom data types.

E.g, from the docs (http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html)

The type you expect

```
public class Account
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public IList<string> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

The data

```
string json = @"{
'Email': 'james@example.com',
'Active': true,
'CreatedDate': '2013-01-20T00:00:00Z',
'Roles': [
    'User',
    'Admin'
    ]
}";
```

Deserialize and access the dictionary, as you would expect

```
Account account = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Account>(json);
Console.WriteLine(account.Email);
```